# Как правильно написать запрос SQL INSERT

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite, запрос, sqlite3

```
def signup_function(self):
    user = str(self.signup_username_line.text())
    passw = str(self.signup_password_line.text())
    if not user or not passw:
        print("Please fill in all inputs")
    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('handler/users.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES {({user},{passw})}")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

вычислил, что проблема заключается в `query`, который я запускаю в `cur.execute`, но не могу понять что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('q1397093_users.db')

user = 'noobdeveloper'
passw = 'Tom12345'
    
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_q1397093(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, password TEXT);")

# +++ ---------------------------------------------------------------->  v      v  v       v    
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users_q1397093(username, password) VALUES ('{user}', '{passw}');")
# +++ ----------------------------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    last_row_id = cur.lastrowid
    print(f"The last Id of the inserted row is {last_row_id}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]